# Jquery-Ajax call not working as expected

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working on a project like this:
(HTML Forms(AJAX)+ twitter bootstrap)(solo HTML, no JSP,etc..)->Servlets(on Google App Engine-JAVA)->Persistence(Google Cloud SQL).

I'm quite new to jQuery ajax calls, but i understand the process, as i'm used to write the old XHR code.
Below is the function in JS, that does not write to console the expected result..so far most of the times form data is persisted.
My Servlet if fine, and outputs a valid JSON.(calling the URL on a browser always works as expected.)

My answer is why jQuery ajax callbacks(done,fail,always) aren't working properly? They do write to console/display alert().
THANKS, for your time!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myEmail = "";
    var myGender = "";

    $('#saveButton').click(function() {
        $('#myform').submit();
        //alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
        myEmail = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
        window.console.log('EMAIL---->' + myEmail);/*ok log!*/
        //alert('EMAIL->' + myEmail);
        var radioObj = document.forms['myForm'].elements['gender'];
        myGender = getCheckedValue(radioObj);
        window.console.log('GENDER---->' + myGender);/*ok log!*/
        //alert('GENDER->' + myGender);
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            statusCode : {
                404 : function() {
                    alert("404 ERROR - page not found");
                }
            },
            url : "/newuser",
            type : "GET",
            timeout : 10000,
            data : {
                email : myEmail,
                gender : myGender,
                operation : '0'
            },
            done : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                window.console.log('done -> RESPONSE---->' + data);/*this does not log!*/
                alert(data);
            },
            fail : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                window.console.log('always -> RESPONSE---->' + data); /*this does not log!*/
                alert(data);
            },
            always : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                window.console.log('always -> RESPONSE---->' + data); /*this does not log!*/
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`done`, `fail` and `always` are *not* properties of the settings object passed to `$.ajax`, they are callbacks on the jqxhr object *returned* by the call to `$.ajax`. They should be configured like this instead:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() { alert("success"); })
  .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
  .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Check out the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for further usage guidance.